# Prove the sequence of general term $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n+1} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

> Given the sequence $$a_n :=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}$$
>   Prove the sequence $(a_{2n+1})_{n \geq 0}$ converges.

**My thoughts**

I've proven that the sequence $(a_{2n+1})_{n \geq 0}$ is monotone decreasing. So now I want to prove that the sequence is bounded below, since then I can prove the sequence converges.
I wanted to prove the sequence is bounded below by induction, however I'm not quite sure how.
Since $$a_{2n+1} :=\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}= 1 -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+...$$
I think it is bounded by $\frac{1}{2}$.

Using induction:

- For $n=0$, we know $a_{2n+1} = a_1 = 1 \geq\frac{1}{2}$
- Suppose that $a_{2n+1} \geq \frac{1}{2}$. Prove that $a_{2(n+1)+1)} = a_{2n+3} \geq \frac{1}{2}$.
  I know that $$a_{2n+3} :=\sum_{k=1}^{2n+3} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} = a_{2n+1} -\frac{1}{2n+2} + \frac{1}{2n+3} = a_{2n+1} -\frac{1}{(2n+2)(2n+3)}$$ But I don't know how to proceed. Any help?

Comment: I think it's even more obvious that $a_{2n+1}\ge0$. You can bracket together terms in the sum to see this.

Comment: $(a_k)$ is a subsequence of the sequence of partial sums of the harmonic alternated series, it's then convergent

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown But is it also possible to show it is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @Whizkid95 Oh yes!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown How ;-) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To show that $a_{2n+1} > \frac12$, note that
$$
a_{2n+1} = \sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} = \underbrace{1 - \frac12}_{=\frac12} + \underbrace{\frac13 - \frac14}_{>0} + \underbrace{\frac15 - \frac16}_{>0} + \ldots + \underbrace{\frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n}}_{>0} + \underbrace{\frac{1}{2n+1}}_{>0} > \frac12.
$$